# 'JEventDispatcher' is deprecated in Joomla 4 and what is the replacement

Tags: custom-component, joomla-4.x

I am using the below code in my current Joomla custom component

```
Joomla\CMS\Plugin\PluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$res = $dispatcher->trigger('onCheckAnswer',$post['recaptcha_response_field']);
```

It seems 'JEventDispatcher' is deprecated in Joomla 4

What would be the equivalent in Joomla 4 style of coding.

Answer (score 4):

The ideal way is to have dependencies injected into your objects. Event dispatcher is registered with the global service container so you can fetch it when registering your component services in `provider.php`. However, there isn't a good way to pass it down to MVC elements without a custom MVC factory. Core components don't use anything like that yet.

That said, if you just want to get your code working, you can trigger the event through the application:

```
$res = Joomla\CMS\Factory::getApplication()->triggerEvent('onCheckAnswer', [$post['recaptcha_response_field']]);
```

Note that this method is already deprecated and will be removed in 5.0. Going forward, an event object should be created and passed to dispatcher's `dispatch()` method:

```
$dispatcher = Joomla\CMS\Factory::getApplication()->getDispatcher();
$event = new Joomla\Event\Event('onCheckAnswer', [$post['recaptcha_response_field']]);
$res = $dispatcher->dispatch('onCheckAnswer', $event);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I do not want to simply make my code to run.  I want the right way to do.  When I tried with your code snippet, it looks like `getDispatcher` is an undefined method inside `Joomla\CMS\Factory::getApplication()`.  Can you please help on that.

Comment: Are you getting an error when running the code? Or does the error appear only in your editor?